# store difference between primary shard and replica shard in es

Tags: elasticsearch, store

Currently I'm importing massive data into an elasticsearch cluster.

When I ran this command:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v'
```

it returned:

```
index              shard prirep state       docs   store ip         node            
...  
logs                20    p      STARTED  8919493   4.3gb 10.2.1.141 Madame Masque   
logs                20    r      STARTED  8918762   8.3gb 10.2.3.253 Seeker     
...
```

Currently I have 28 shards, each shard has one replica.

So I'm wondering why there is a huge difference between the store value of the two shards.

Thanks!

Comment: 28 shards, how many servers in the cluster?

Comment: Can you run a _optimize and paste the output of the same.

Comment: 22 servers, and 20 of them are data nodes.

Comment: I'm still bulk indexing data into the cluster. Once it's done, I'll run optimization.